# Python CSV reading unnecessary adding quotes

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am having following CSV

```
"name","isTrue","ID"
"ashok",True, 12
```

When I read it using `dictRead` values are appended with single quotes.

For example, output would be:

```
["name" : 'ashok', "isTrue":'True', "ID":'12']
```

I don't want it to add quotes for `True` and `12` value since I didn't have quotes in my CSV. I tried using regular file read, but again splitting the line yields list of string.

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: You need to show your code.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to manually set the required type.

**Ex:**

```
import csv
res = []
with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    r = csv.DictReader(infile, delimiter=',')
    for i in r:
        i["isTrue"] = True if i["isTrue"] == 'True' else False
        i["ID"] = int(i["ID"])
        res.append(i)
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'name': 'ashok', 'isTrue': True, 'ID': 12}]
```

Comment: I cant check for each column name since column names can be anything and data can be of any type just that only string values will be enclosed within quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the quotes are *added* to the data being read. I believe the quotation marks are just an indication of the data type of the read content being string. The rest of my answer assumes that your chief concern is the data type of the deserialized (i.e. read from CSV) content, and not the quotation marks.

Since CSV is a text file, it is not exactly possible for the deserializing process to infer the data type of the individual columns without any context. That is, you should somehow pass that deserialization function the data type information on the columns, if you want it to be able to do it while reading from the CSV file.

Another approach is post-processing the deserialized string data. After reading the contents of the CSV, assuming that each column have a specific data type, you can do a secondary processing on the data to transform individual columns into their correct data types.

Say, after reading the CSV, your data is stored in a list of dicts named `output`.

```
transformations = {'isTrue' : lambda x: x == 'True',
                   'ID' : lambda x: int(x)}
for row in output:
    for key, val in row:
        if key in transformations:
            row[key] = transformations(val)
# output now contains the data in the desired form
```

Note that you can expand the `transformations` dictionary based on your needs and the specific CSV file you are processing.

Unless you have a specific, predetermined CSV file, though, there aren't a lot of robust methods that can help you guess the data type for the columns for an arbitrary table.

One method could be using regular expressions to check all the values seen in a column to find out the possible data types of that column. And then, you may have a precedence between the data types, and pick them accordingly.

Below is a crude implementation of what I described in the paragraph above. For simplicity, let's assume `checkIfBool`, `checkIfInt`, `checkIfFloat` are methods that take a single string as input and return a boolean value based on their regex comparison.

```
data_types = ['float', 'int', 'bool']
data_type_transformations = {'float': lambda x: float(x),
                             'int': lambda x: int(x),
                             'bool': lambda x: x == 'True'}
column_list = output[0].keys()
column_possible_types_dict = {}
for column in column_list:
    column_possible_types_dict[column] = set(data_types)

# Eliminate data types that are impossible for that column to have
for row in output:
    for key, val in row:
        if not checkIfFloat(val):
            column_possible_types_dict.remove('float')
        if not checkIfInt(val):
            column_possible_types_dict.remove('int')
        if not checkIfBool(val):
            column_possible_types_dict.remove('bool')

# Decide which data type columns will have
# based on a precedence predetermined by you
column_types = []
for column in column_list:
    if 'float' in column_possible_types_dict:
        column_types.append('float')
    elif 'int' in column_possible_types_dict:
        column_types.append('int')
    elif 'bool' in column_possible_types_dict:
        column_types.append('bool')
    else:
        column_types.append('string')

# Conduct the transformations
for row in output:
    for key, val in row:
        if column_types[key] != 'string':
            row[key] = data_type_transformations(val)
# output now contains the data in the desired form
```

Comment: I cant add transformations since column names can be anything and data can be of any type just that only string values will be enclosed within quotes.@ilim

Comment: @ashokkumarangadi I updated my answer to offer a more general solution that may be more general.

Answer (score 0):

Python csv module does not add any quotes. It simply assumes that a csv file contains *text* fields optionaly enclosed in quotes and separated with a delimiter. It removes the optional quotes, but will never convert any string to its boolean or numerical value: this is up to the programmer.

To make sure, just execute the following piece of code:

```
row = {"name" : 'ashok', "isTrue":'True', "ID":'12'}
for k in row:
    print(k, row[k])
```

You obtain:

```
name ashok
isTrue True
ID 12
```

with no quotes.

Only the default conversion of dict to string adds quotes around text values to allow to distinguish them from numerical or boolean ones.